# How to convert Selenium IDE (.SIDE) recordings to Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework, selenium-ide, format-conversion

I'm just after recording a Selenium IDE Recording with Google Chrome. I've saved the `.SIDE` -extension file, and now I'm wondering -- how would I go about converting this file format into `.robot` so I could use it on Robot Framework?

Answer (score 2):

You may use Katalon Recorder instead:

https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/katalon-automation-recorder/

"This is the Selenium IDE-compatible replacement on latest Chrome and Firefox that helps record, play, debug, manage automated tests, and export to C#, Java, Ruby, Python, Groovy, or **Robot Framework**."

I tried it briefly, it works very well so far.

Answer (score 1):

[denschu has created a plugin](https://github.com/denschu/selenium-ide-format-robotframework/blob/master/robotframework-rc.js) that will export RF synatx from a SIDE source.

Note that it is only intended to be used for short reusable bits of workflow. So you may have to change your assumptions if you were thinking "I have a big `.side` file that I want in `.robot` format".  If that's where you are, this will only help going forward — or for you to reverse engineer small pieces, to setup a strategy for a bigger migration.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using it currently for the following steps: 1. Enter a website 2. Click on textfield 3. Input email address 4. Click on textfield 5. Input password 6. Click on button.  So not very complex.